# How to switch between activities dynamically and efficiently in android?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I am developing an android game in which there are near about 50 levels and each level represents a single `activity` . E.g. `Level1`, `Level2`...`Level50`. 
After completion of every level I am switching to `LevelUpActivity` where I am showing the current score and level of player along with Level Up message. On button click I am switching to next level of the game. Now my question is that how can I switch to next `activity` (level) when I am having the current level number? 
E.g. Suppose I have cleared `Level2` then I want to jump on `Level3` from `LevelUpActivity` what are the efficient ways to do that? Currently I am getting success for this task by using Switch Case statements. But will it be working efficiently for 50 or more than that numbers to check and then switch activities accordingly? 
Following code snippet shows the class definition of `LevelUpActivity`

```
public class LevelUpActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
Button btn_continue;
TextView scoreview, levelview;
int score, level;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.level_up);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    score = bundle.getInt("score");
    level = bundle.getInt("levelno");
    System.out.println("Current Score = " + score);

    levelview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.levelView);
    levelview.setText("Level " + level + " Completed");
    scoreview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score);
    scoreview.setText(score + "");

    btn_continue = (Button) findViewById(R.id.levelbtn);
    btn_continue.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v.getId() == R.id.levelbtn) {
        Intent i;
        switch (level) {
            case 1:
                i = new Intent(this, Level2.class);
                i.putExtra("score", score);
                startActivity(i);
                break;

            case 2:
                i = new Intent(this, Level3.class);
                i.putExtra("score", score);
                startActivity(i);
                break;

            case 3:
                i = new Intent(this, Level3.class);
                i.putExtra("score", score);
                startActivity(i);
                break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The performance of the switch statement won't be significantly decrease with the number of statements. The switch statement will be incredibly long though.

Assuming that every `level` Activity is following the same interface, (i.e. they accept a "score" and nothing else), then you can instead just put all your levels in an array.

```
private static final Class<Activity>[] levels = [
   Level1.class,
   Level2.class,
   Level3.class,
   ...
   Level4.class
]
```

Then just retrieve them like so:

```
int levelNumber = someMethodToGetLevelNumber();
Class<Activity> levelClass = levels[levelNumber]; 
Intent i = new Intent(this, Level2.class);
i.putExtra("score", score);
startActivity(i);
```